# Android Create Video Thumbnail at specific time

Tags: android, video, time

I already got it to create a thumbnail from my video.
The code looks like this:

```
videoGalleryThumbnails.add(ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(
                    videoFile.getAbsolutePath(), MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND), 500, 200));
```

But the thumbnail created is at a really bad time. It is exactly when the video is black. Now i have no use of a completely black Thumbnail.

How can i take a Thumbnail of my video at a specific time? E.g. at 00:31 or at 01:44?

Or is it not possible?

I tried also to use MediaMetadataRetriever, but i get only a white image. Code looks like this

```
File tempVideoList[] = (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(PATH_VIDEO_GALLERY))
            .listFiles();
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
Bitmap myBitmap=null;
for (File videoFile : tempVideoList) {
    if (videoFile.isFile()) {
        //from here
        try {
            retriever.setDataSource(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
            myBitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(11); //at 11th second
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.i("MyDebugCode", "MediaMetadataRetriever got exception:" + ex);
        }

    videoGalleryThumbnails.add(myBitmap);
    //to here
}
```

If i replace the code marked as "from here" to "to here" with the top first code, it works.
I also tried MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST and OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC and OPTION_NEXT_SYNC.

Comment: Can you check and share the videoFile declaration?

Comment: I edited my code, so you see the declaration. It seems fine so far.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok i got it.
The MediaMetadataRetriever was absolutely the right way to go. The problem is, that it counts the time in microseconds and not in seconds. Solution looks like this:

```
try {
        retriever.setDataSource(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
        int timeInSeconds = 30;
        myBitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(timeInSeconds * 1000000,
                    MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC); 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.i("MyDebugCode", "MediaMetadataRetriever got exception:" + ex);
    }

videoGalleryThumbnails.add(myBitmap);
```

I don't know, if OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC is actually needed, but it looks like this is the better way for programming.

Thanks to William Riley for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Small improvement suggestion: using `TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros(timeInSeconds)` would be safer than getting confused with the amount of zeros

Answer (score 0):

need little changes for this code:

```
try {

    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
```

//have to control the version for the setDataSource

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
       retriever.setDataSource(video_path, new HashMap<String, String>());
   else
       retriever.setDataSource(video_path);
   int timeInSeconds = 5;
   Bitmap thumb = retriever.getFrameAtTime(timeInSeconds * 1000000,
                                MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
   imageViewThumb.setImageBitmap(thumb);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
   }
```

if we don't control the version for "**setDataSource**" then we will get exceptions. for me it was not working until version controlling.