# Getting Thumbnail from video which is not Youtube, Dailymotion?

Tags: android, video, thumbnails, mediametadataretriever

I am developping an Android application and I encouter problem to get thumbnail of video.
My question is simple. I know how to get thumbnail for Youtube or Dailymotion but is there a way to do the same for a video like this one : http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/MP4/ConvertedFiles/MediaCoder/MediaCoder_test3_1m10s_MPEG4SP_VBR_516kbps_320x240_25fps_MPEG1Layer3_CBR_320kbps_Stereo_44100Hz.mp4

I want to get a frame at time T for every video.

I tried this :

```
Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(m_Video.getM_Urlvideo(),
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

`m_Video.getM_Urlvideo()` is returning my video url..

It doesn't work, anyone has an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: File isn't corrupted?, policy is allowing you to access the video?

Comment: @MarcosEusebi I can access to the video and stream it in my app. I just need to get a frame of it

Comment: Btw I have an corrupted file error http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html and if you need a spesific frame this question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331624/android-create-video-thumbnail-at-specific-time