# Get Multiple Thumbnail Images From Video In Android Studio At least 4 to 6

Tags: android, image, file, video, mp4

I have a video file path like this
I want to display multiple thumbnail from that video at least 4 to 6

```
String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20170630_123146.mp4"
```

And i have image views like this.I want to store those thumbnail in  this image views.

So i tried like this

```
ImageView imageview_mini = 
 (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_mini);
    ImageView imageview_mini1 = 
(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_mini1);
    ImageView imageview_mini2 = 
(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_mini2);
    ImageView imageview_mini3 = 
(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_mini3);

 Bitmap bmThumbnail;

    bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    imageview_mini.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

    bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, 
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    imageview_mini1.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

    bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, 
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    imageview_mini2.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);

    bmThumbnail = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(filePath, 
    MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
    imageview_mini3.setImageBitmap(bmThumbnail);
```

but here only displaying thumbnail as a video of first frame i mean all image views storing same thumbnail is there any way achieve this to get multiple thumbnails from video
  I tried some library ffmpeg but i didn't get understand and i failed
Can anybody solve this

Thanks in advance

i tried like this again   output: image view  showing empty space

`String filePath =path; "/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/my_video.mp4";`

```
    ImageView imageview_mini = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.thumbnail_mini);

    try {

        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
       //have to control the version for the setDataSource

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
            retriever.setDataSource(path, new HashMap<String, String>());
        else
            retriever.setDataSource(path);
        int timeInSeconds = 5;
        Bitmap thumb = retriever.getFrameAtTime(timeInSeconds * 1000000,
                MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
        imageview_mini.setImageBitmap(thumb);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.v("MyDebugCode", "MediaMetadataRetriever got exception:" + ex);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Create Video Thumbnail at specific time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331624/android-create-video-thumbnail-at-specific-time)

Comment: that solution not worked for me@VladMatvienko

Comment: `not worked` how exactly?

Comment: sorry @VladMatvienko i didn't get you i pasted my code above how i tried can you check

Comment: I mean how do you know that it didn't work? it crashed? showed errors? didn't show images? showed wrong images? in wrong resolution? ...

Comment: image displaying empty i mean white page

Comment: do you get any exceptions in the log?

Comment: no exceptions also coming sir @VladMatvienko

Comment: try using `timeInSeconds * 1000`

Comment: yes i changed lot @VladMatvienko like 10...100..1000.. i tried